# Make Expect throw error on unexpected output

Tags: testing, command-line-interface, expect

I'm using the following [expect script](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) `test.exp` to test a CLI application I'm developing:

```
spawn ./note_trainer.exe --seed 0

expect "note_trainer using seed 0"
expect "Note G# transposed down 6 semi-tones gives what? "
send "D\r"
expect "Correct!\r"
send "\004"
```

The script works as intended: it waits for the appropriate output from
the process, sends a string, and obtains the correct result. However,
I would like the expect script to fail if `note_trainer.exe` does not
behave intended.

Specifically, if the `./note_trainer.exe` returns "Incorrect!" instead
"Correct!", I want `expect test.exp` to fail in someway, and return an
error code.

Currently, all it does is wait until a timeout is reached, and then
exit with error code 0.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is match the timeout in each expect statement, and make it exit if found. However, it is much better to take advantage of the `expect_after` command to effectively automatically add a match for timeout to *every* following expect command. Just add after the spawn:

```tcl
expect_after timeout {send_user "Timeout!"; exit 1}
```

See `man expect`.

Answer (score 0):

The `expect` command can watch for multiple patterns:

```
expect {
    "Incorrect" {error "Wrong answer."}
    "Correct!\r"
}
send "\004"
```